# Подобрать БД для хранения данных о школах

Tags: access, c#, база-данных, sql

Нашему отделу поставили задачу разработать БД и приложение к нему. БД будет включать список 450 школ нашей республика. Изначально конечно БД ограничиться всего лишь контактами самой школы и составом учителей. Но в будущем предполагается, что туда будет вводиться более подробная информации включая, адреса школьников. Какие более подробные данные БД будет содержать пока не известно. Нужна также программа для оперирования запросами к БД, рассчитанная на рядового пользователя. Программой будут пользоваться как наше учреждение, так и сотрудники школ, учет которых мы собираемся вводит. 
Базы данных такого масштабы я ранее не делал. Обходился лишь БД для своих небольших приложений и сайтов. С директором пока остановились на `MS Access`. Знаю языки c++, c#, `python`, `java`. Думаю выбрать C# наверное он будет более тесно связан с `Windows` и `Access`. 
Поделитесь, пожалуйста, своими мыслями как лучше организовать данный процесс?. Если нужно какая-то уточненная информации, то спросите, я постараюсь дать развернутый ответ. 
Первый макет приложения и варианты таблиц БД мне необходимо представить в течении недели.

1. Может поменять MS Access на другую базу?
2. Может сделать сначала приложение и заполнять базу сразу из него?

Comment: Акцесс вполне достаточен, но можно выбрать и любую другую базу. Сложность использования определяется вашим приложением, а не базой данных. Кстати, если это сетевой проект, то Акцесс подходит не так хорошо, но тоже может быть использован.

Comment: @derkode, если в перспективе 450 школ целой республики, то дальше будут бюджетные деньги. Их надо грамотно освоить. Для этого проект должен быть расширяемым, постоянно растущим (хотя бы на бумаге).

Лучше всего прописывайте сразу СУБД Oracle и Linux кластер с устройствами хранения в NAS/SAN.

--

А пока можете назвать свой проект прототипом. Но тогда все равно лучше делать сразу на Linux (и например, MySQL или Postgres).

Comment: т.е. делать на Linux  и размещать сразу в Интернете? Или в сети держать один компьютер на Linux и на ней хранить БД?

Comment: >делать на Linux и размещать сразу в Интернете? Или в сети держать один компьютер на Linux и на ней хранить БД?

Вообще-то это равнозначные варианты. В любом случае БД должна жить на компьютере под Linux и быть размещена в интернете (но при этом не обязательно быть в открытом доступе, само собой)

Comment: Если условно возьмем Linux + MySQL + Python. Наверное лучше сразу делать клиентское приложение и через него заполнять БД? А есть разница в дистрибутиве? Ubuntu сойдет?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В мире есть 3 основных вендора БД: Microsoft, Oracle и IBM - все остальное это пыль под ногами.

У каждого из вендоров есть своя линейка БД от малых до очень больших.

Для ваших целей отлично подойдут практически любые из младших серий этих вендоров: MySQL, Oracle Express, SQL Server Express, IBM DB2 Express. Плюс здесь в том, что в случае если ваша БД вдруг резко станет большой, то перенести их под взрослые БД не составит труда.

А если же вы не послушаетесь взрослых дядей и сядете под некую вещь в себе Postgres (очень люблю и уважаю), Sybase или Mongo - то потом не говорите, что вас не предупреждали :)

Comment: Замечание очень понравилось, а что на счет Access?

Comment: Access это офисная декстоп приблуда малоприспособленная для сетевой работы. На нем только тренироваться или использовать для вычисления сложных экселеподобных запросиков. Еще Access пригоден для использования в качестве удобного (надо признать) клиента к большим БД. Для ваших целей он не подходит. Выкиньте его пока не поздно, а то потом наплачетесь.

Comment: И наверное тоже рекомендуете сразу устанавливать на Linux-машину?

Comment: Зависит от выбранной СУБД. Mssql на линукс ставить сложно, для остальных можно взять солярис.

Comment: Ага. Солярис. И не мелочиться, сразу на спарке. И энтерпрайзного оракла туда взгромоздить, и гномом обвеситься, а чо? Вот развлекуха будет для человека, который ещё ни одного линукса без иксов не видел...

Comment: @derkode сразу ставить Linux советуют только идиоты. Все зависит от задачи и выбранной схемы работы ну и от финансирования кстати тоже. Если вам выделен бюджет на лицензии то можно поставить и Windows. Если с этим впритык, то тут без вариантов. Советую предложить 2 варианта: с Windows + SQL Server Express и Linux + MySQL.

Comment: @maxleo ну да на солярке можно неплохо попилить бюджетные бабки :)

Answer (score 4):

Лицензировать Oracle или SQL Server мне кажется бессмысленным, т.к. практически любой сервер баз данных справится с вашей нагрузкой.
Я бы посоветовал в качестве клиентского ПО - набор форм (MDI - это классика) + Entity Framework для взаимодействия с базой. 
EF5 и выше может подключать MySQL  - ей можно и воспользоваться

Comment: Да, к тому же EF может подключаться к acces

Answer (score 0):

Если разрабатывать будете самостоятельно, то советую выбрать My Visual Database, проще чем MS Access и бесплатная.
http://drive-software.com/myvisualdatabase_ru.html

но эта база будет работать только по локалке или через удаленный рабочий стол, т.к. нет полноценного клиент сервера

Answer (score -1):

Порекомендую: 1с версия "предприятие".
Преимущества:

- легка в освоении и установке;
- установку и настройку можно сделать самостоятельно;
- имеется визуальный конструктор, а это
  значит легко создавать свою базу данных (учетную систему), добавлять
  атрибуты, таблицы, справочники, создавать отчеты;
- самостоятельно поддерживать сможете, а при необходимости технической поддержки, в принципе не так дорого;